# Using OpenVPN with Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, vpn, openvpn

We have, currently, 7 Developers on our team. All of them require the ability to have read access to a remote repository, in this case an Artifactory, server.

I could get them all to make an account, but I figure it would be more efficient doing the following: Connecting Artifactory and the Developers to a VPN and have them read off the RRM (Remote Repository Manager) that way.

The problem conspires when I do not know how to do such a thing with OpenVPN in regards to generating a client that can connect to the VPN using only a username, passsword, and the full hostname of the VPN server, as I assume the `Proxy` section on Artifactory is where you add credentials to connect to a VPN. How would I achieve this?